# Google search console hacked, how do I resolve such things?

Tags: wordpress, google-search-console

I have a WordPress site that is using the google search console facility and I observed that someone with ybh19960101@gmail.com is allowing himself to google search console services, how I can find out the user and how is he allowing himself to add header tags to the WordPress site?

Comment: Have you checked this https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9044101?hl=en

Comment: No, I didn't I will try this

Comment: I have observed that there is a file in the root directory that does not belong to the site it's name kaylin.php and recently added, should I delete it?

Comment: I think it is Japanese Backdoor Malware. check this https://www.getastra.com/e/malware/infections/japanese-backdoor-wordpress-hack

Comment: See this also for temporary solotion https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7281924?hl=en

Comment: @techfangirl second last suggestion of yours worked for me, can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer support questions are off-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is Japanese Backdoor Malware. check this
https://www.getastra.com/e/malware/infections/japanese-backdoor-wordpress-hack

See this also for temporary solution https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7281924?hl=en